# Print binary search tree in order, but the variable isnt the primary one in the struct

Tags: algorithm, sorting, binary-search-tree

So this is the problem, I insert in my binary search tree the following elements:

```
Number  Name   Age 
1       abc     2
2       abcd    1
```

I can sort it by using the number since I use it as the key variable, but how can I sort it by age? I tough about creating an array and transfer all the elements and sort them inside the array but that doesn't seem right, there most be a way to do it more properly. Any tips?

Comment: Build a new ST keyed by age? Unless there is any correlation between the Number and the Age, there's nothing you can do apart from re-sorting. Of course you could do (complexity-wise) better using bucket sort than you would do rebuilding the tree with age as the key since age probably is bounded.

Comment: But in a binary search tree i guess we can't have the same value as primary variable, and age would repeat several times.

Comment: That depends on whether the tree implements a strict order on its keys or a preorder (meaning an order that allows for less or equal, not meaning pre-order traversal here!). You can implement a BST such that it works with a preordered multiset as well (meaning you can have the same value multiple times). It's just a matter of being consistent. Generally in BSTs you have the values smaller than your current key in the left child tree and the values greater than your cur. key in the right child tree. You can extend this so the left child tree maintains values less than or equal to the cur. key.

Comment: The downside to this is that you get subpaths of length linear in the number of times you add the same value to the tree, so this may degenerate. So the smart thing to do probably would be to sort by age in linear time (bucket sort for example, just use a number of buckets equal to the highest age value).

Comment: Alternatively, if you do want to go with a BST, augment it to keep the multiplicity of the keys (that means keep track of how many times the age is in the set, increasing the counter on insert and decreasing it on delete, truely deleting the value out of the tree only once the counter becomes 0). This will maintain the complexities of the operations just like a common BST has them because it won't change the size and shape of the tree while still managing a multiset.